# Whats the Easiest Way to Extract All Columns From a Complex Type Using ADF Mapping Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a json file I am transforming with an ADF Data Flow.   The file has has some complex type properties which have a 1 to 1 relationship with the main row, it is not an array.  I know I can extract columns from the complex type using a derived column such as MyDerivedColumn1 = ComplexType.Column1, MyDerivedColumn2 = ComplexType.Column2, etc..; however there are a lot of columns in the complex type and the creation of a derived column for each is a bit tedious.  I was hoping someone could enlighten me to some magical button or function which could do all that work for me similar to when transforming a complex type in Power BI.  In PBI all I have to do is click a button at the column header of the complex type and it adds a Table.ExpandRecordColumn function to the M code and all the complex type columns are promoted to the top level record.

A simplified version of the json would look like this...

```
{
    "Col1": "Col1Value",
    "Col2": "Col2Value",
    "Col3": "Col3Value",
    "ComplexType": {
        "ComplexCol1": "ComplexType1Value",
        "ComplexCol2": "ComplexType2Value",
        "ComplexCol3": "ComplexType3Value"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **select** transformation to extract these dynamically.

This is sample data from the above JSON:

[image]

In select transformation, Go to **Add mapping -> Rule-based mapping** and give it like below. Delete the original mapping for the `ComplexType` object so that you won't get that JSON in your output.

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: is it possible to prefix the column with their parent column´s name?