# Azure Data Factory: Parsing JSON column in CSV

Tags: azure-data-factory

Doing my first steps in Azure Data Factory:

I am trying to extract json values from a json document in a column of a csv file.

```
c1,c2,c3
1,ABC,{"name": "Joe", "age": 33}
2,XYZ,{"name": "Bob", "age": 44}
3,MNC,{"name": "Dan", "age": 55}
```

I try the simple csv file above as source and another one as sink. In the middle I use the parse function.

It should all be straightforward, but I fail with "selecting" certain items from the given column c3 (which has the json-documents - in theory, the document could be deeply nested!) and creating a new column that contains only the selected value.

In the Parse settings I choose:

- json
- document per line
- columns:

  - Column: newCol,
  - Expression: c3,
  - Output column type: (name as string)

The problem is (as it seems), that it understands "(name as string)" as a complex type and cant write it to a column.

I am doing something conceptually (or some low-level technical things) wrong I feel, but I dont get it.

There are other straihgt forward examples out there, so I am sure that I am on the right track: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/data-flow-formatters-flatten-parse-and-stringify-in-azure-data-factory

I have also seen similar stackoverflow questions (but lost the references), for the basic requirement. the simple answer was "use the parse function" ...

The actual error message for reference:

> The following column(s) have a complex structure which can only be written to Snowflake, REST, ORC, JSON, AVRO, and Azure Cosmos DB: 'newCol'. Please remove the columns or update the sink to Snowflake, REST, ORC, JSON, AVRO, or Azure Cosmos DB.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same approach as in the link that you have provided and got same error while using csv sink.

[image]

> The problem is (as it seems), that it understands "(name as string)" as a complex type and cant write it to a column.

Yes, this is the cause of the error. To resolve this and to get the csv output with required columns, you need to generate the individual column from the complex column.

Go to **Mapping of the sink**-> **uncheck Auto mapping** -> **select the `newCol.name` from the drop down** of input columns and give the name in the output columns.

[image]

You can see when I did the same, I am able to solve the error. Here I am deleting the extra column(`c3`) in this mapping.

**Result csv file:**

[image]

If you have more columns in the complex column, click on the **Add mapping -> Rules based mapping** from the above. Use the Rule based mapping as like this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76129310/18836744).

Comment: Thank you Rakesh, I think this will solve the problem, however, now I ran into the problem that the parse steps fails with "Document form is set to 'Document per line', but schema is not an array type." - But I believe that "Document per line" is the correct one. I wonder, if the CSV is parsed correctly in terms of escaping and quotes. Sadly I don't have the time to play around with it too much (and the debugging takes very long)

Comment: yeah, I have gone through that error, it will give proper result when you select `Single Document` as the JSON settings. In the above I have selected that option only. If it solves your problem, it's better to make the answer as accepted as this will be beneficial to other community members.